# kubernetes allow privileged local testing cluster

Tags: kubernetes

I'm busy testing out kubernetes on my local pc using https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/docs/getting-started-guides/docker.md

which launches a dockerized single node `k8s` cluster. I need to run a privileged container inside k8s (it runs docker in order to build images from dockerfiles). What I've done so far is add a security context `privileged=true` to the pod config which returns forbidden when trying to create the pod. I know that you have to enable privileged on the node with `--allow-privileged=true` and I've done this by adding the parameter arg to step two (running the master and worker node) but it still returns forbidden when creating the pod.

Anyone know how to enable privileged in this dockerized k8s for testing?

Here is how I run the `k8s` master:

```
docker run --privileged --net=host -d -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock  gcr.io/google_containers/hyperkube:v1.0.1 /hyperkube kubelet --api-servers=http://localhost:8080 --v=2 --address=0.0.0.0 --allow-privileged=true --enable-server --hostname-override=127.0.0.1 --config=/etc/kubernetes/manifests
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Update: Privileged mode is now enabled by default (both in the apiserver and in the kubelet) starting with the 1.1 release of Kubernetes.

---

To enable privileged containers, you need to pass the `--allow-privileged` flag to the Kubernetes apiserver *in addition* to the Kubelet when it starts up. The manifest file that you use to launch the Kubernetes apiserver in the single node docker example is bundled into the image (from [master.json](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/cluster/images/hyperkube/master.json)), but you can make a local copy of that file, add the `--allow-privileged=true` flag to the apiserver command line, and then change the `--config` flag you pass to the Kubelet in Step Two to a directory containing your modified file.

Comment: I've tried this by mounting the edited master.json file as a volume and verified that it does mount properly. This however causes the api server to not run. Are you sure it must be done on the api server? from what I've read you have to allow privileged on every kubelet.

Comment: You need to do it on the kubelet *and* the apiserver (sorry that wasn't very clear before, I've updated the answer).

Comment: Ah,  I was already doing that anyways, I actually wasn't looking at the master.json properly and didn't realise that ${VERSION} in master.json was being dynamically changed when running the makefile. After fixing that it works now.

Comment: Just a quick side note, how easy is it to dockerize kubernetes if I were to change some code like add a storage plugin or modify the scheduler? Does the automated build create the  `hyperkube` binary used to dockerize kubernetes? Currently the makefile downloads this binary from an official k8s release instead of using a binary built on the machine.

Comment: If you want to change some code and run a custom version of the scheduler or kubelet you can modify the makefile to push to / pull from your own docker registry (either private or public) and build your own hyperkube images.